# ImageTK not rendering image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a 5x5 grid of randomly generated images. When I run the following code, the window pops up in the correct size, but none of the images that were supposed to be in the labels:

```
col = 0
for array in (a,b,c,d,e):
    ro = 0
    for item in array:
        if item == 0:
            path = "W.jpg"
        elif item == 1:
            path = "P.jpg"
        elif item == 2:
            path = "D.jpg"
        elif item == 3:
            path = "H.jpg"
        elif item == 4:
            path = "M.jpg"
        elif item == 5:
            path = "F.jpg"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        Label(window, image = img).grid(column = ro, row = col)
        ro += 1
    col += 1
print(final)
```

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also; what is the values of a, b, c, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `img` will be overwritten by new instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` in for loop, so the previous reference of `img` will be lost and the previous image will be destroyed.  To overcome it, declare a global list to hold the image reference as below:

```
imagefiles = ['W.jpg', 'P.jpg', 'D.jpg', 'H.jpg', 'M.jpg', 'F.jpg']
images = [] # list to hold the image references
for col, array in enumerate((a, b, c, d, e)):
    for ro, item in enumerate(array):
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagefiles[item]))) # save the image reference
        Label(window, image=images[-1]).grid(row=col, column=ro)
```

Or you can attach the image reference to the Label instance as below:

```
imagefiles = ['W.jpg', 'P.jpg', 'D.jpg', 'H.jpg', 'M.jpg', 'F.jpg']
for col, array in enumerate((a, b, c, d, e)):
    for ro, item in enumerate(array):
        lbl = Label(window)
        lbl.grid(row=col, column=ro)
        lbl.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagefiles[item])) # attach the image reference to label instance variable
        lbl.config(image=lbl.image)
```